# htaccess rule with exception doesn't work properly

Tags: .htaccess, exception

I want to redirect all urls under a domain, to another domain, except one or 2 urls.
For example, all urls under domain1.com redirect to domain2.com except the url "domain1.com/cat01"
I wrote this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cat01$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works in all urls but it redirects "domain1.com/cat01" to "domain2.com/index.php"!
I tried other ways (for example excepting by regex in rewriterule ... but the problem was exsist!
(I use joomla htaccess codes there too)

Comment: Have you tried using the [`loglevel` and `rewritelog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) directives so you can see what it being matched?

Comment: How? (My urls are not a folder! They are a PHP address)

Comment: Depending on the versions you would change your server config to increase the log level of the mod_rewrite module.  Then check your access log after an incorrect rewrite to see what was being compared to your regex.  It may be important that rewrite rules processed in .htaccess files have the path to the directory removed before rewriting.  Have you tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cat01$`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joe

I found another way. I installed ReDJ component on my Joomla,and the problem solved.

but also that way won't work I think:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cat01$
```

Because I've tried that with and without "/" at start.